# How JVM decides in which order to initialize classes (invoke <clinit>)?

Tags: jvm

From my knowledge, when JVM is loading and generating code for A's clinit, if it encounters an unresolved class B, the compiler will first emit a method call to JVM internal to initialize B, then compile the method call/field use of B normally. So at run-time, B is ensured to be initialized before its field or method is used.

Please correct me if I made any mistake in the above.

Then I don't understand how JVM deal with a situation like below.

```
public class A {
  public static A a = new A(B.b);
  public A(B b) {
    a = null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(a == null);
  }
}

public class B {
  public static B b = new B(A.a);
  public B(A a) {}
}
```

Could someone explain how these two classes get initialized since they both need the other part to be initialized first? And why the main method in A returns false, since the static field a should be set null in A's constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second question is easy; the order of operations for the static initialization of `A` is: `B.b` is evaluated, `new A(B.b)` is evaluated (setting `a` to `null`), `a` is assigned `new A(B.b)`. If any other instances of `A` were created, then `a` would be null. I think this should be easy to see without detailed knowledge about class initialization.

The first question is a bit more involved. The relevant chapter in the JLS is [chapter 12 on execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12). The basic idea is this: first a class is loaded, then it is linked, then it is initialized. As part of the linking, the class is prepared; this is when its static fields are created and set to their default values, which is `null` for references ([JLS 12.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3.2)) -- this happens before `static` initalization.

So things happen in this order: `A` is loaded and linked, so `a` is initialized to `null`. Then the static initializer runs, so `new A(B.b)` needs to be evaluated. Now `B` is loaded and linked, and its static initializer runs, and `new B(A.a)` is evaluated, and at this point `a` is `null` and nothing special happens. Then `A`'s constructor runs and the newly created object is assigned to `a`.

Comment: That answers my question. I tested if a==null in B's constructor, and it is true. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great answer. But one point I am confused about is new A(B.a) actually is symbolic reference in bytecode. Does the resolution of this symbolic reference trigger the loading of class B? I don't understand what you mean by 'evaluated'. I don't see this word in JLS.